# Finding word or characters count in uitextview on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

i want to learn searching word or characters count on uitextview.

i used: rangeOfIndex(uitextfield.text)

but this is only find me one namely first one. if uitextview contains 4 times same word, rangeOfIndex show me only first.

thank you.

Comment: `NSRegularExpression` is prpobably what you want, it can find multiple instances.

Comment: Cool! i found what i want thanks to you:)

Comment: @ardacankaya : could you post how you did?

Comment: sorry i forgot, now available

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 let searchString = "abc"
 let baseString = "This is DEMO APP abc \"abc\" more th. abcabcABCAbc."

 let attributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: baseString)

 var error: NSError?
 let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchString, options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)

 if let regexError = error {
println("Oh no! \(regexError)")
  }   
 else {
    for match in regex.matchesInString(baseString, options: NSMatchingOptions.allZeros, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: baseString.utf16Count)) as [NSTextCheckingResult] {
    attributed.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellowColor(), range: match.range)
  }

textView.attributedText = attributed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For counting characters in UITextField.text, you can use countElements() method.

```
let textfield:UITextField = UITextField()
textfield.text = "same word same word"
let count = countElements(textfield.text) // count will have value of 19
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var count = 0
    let text2 = txtArama.text.lowercaseString as NSString
    let text = txtMetin.text.lowercaseString as NSString
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: txtMetin.attributedText)
    println("\(text.length)")
    println("\(text2.length)")
    var aralik:NSRange
    var checker:NSString = ""

    for(var i=0 ; i <= text.length - text2.length ; i++)
    {
        aralik = NSMakeRange(i, text2.length)
        checker = text.substringWithRange(aralik)
        if(text2 == checker)
        {
            attributedText.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.5, blue: 1, alpha: 0.2) ,
                range: aralik)
            txtMetin.attributedText = attributedText
            count++
        }
    }
    println("\(count)")
    lblArananKelime.text = txtArama.text.lowercaseString
    lblArananKelimeSayisi.text = toString(count)
```

i hope this helps you